# Cloudflare page rule- exclude specific URL path containing string

Tags: javascript, url, wildcard, cloudflare

I'm redirecting all the requests on my `website www.example.com/us/*` to  `demo.example.com`.
But want to exclude a specific URL [www.example.com/us/reset-username](http://www.example.com/us/reset-username).

[image]

Comment: Don't see how that could be done in one rule, if the only available wildcard is `*`. Maybe you can set up a rule that "does nothing" for that specific URL, so that once that rule applies, the more general one doesn't get evaluated any more? (If that is possible, I don't know how exactly this works at Cloudflare.)